# populating a matrix with 1s row-wise

Tags: r, matrix, modeling

I know how to randomly populate a matrix with 1s using the 'rbinom' function. However, I need to populate a matrix such that each row has only one 1 and every column has at least one 1 but more than one 1 is ok.

My empty matrix looks like this:

```
Chickens <- matrix(0,600,20)
```

So I need a total of 600 '1s' in the matrix. Thanks for your help!

Comment: ```diag(Chickens) =1``` will solve your requirements but it won't follow a binomial distribution.

Answer (score 3):

If the number of rows is that much bigger than the number of columns you can use `sample` to generate randnom numbers between 1 and 20 and use that to fill the matrix with 1s.

```
set.seed(1)
Chickens[cbind(1:600, sample(1:20, 600, replace = TRUE))] <- 1
```

If the number of rows should only be slightly larger than the number of columns you can still start with `sample` but you would than need to remove duplicated columns at some point.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to create the results matrix beforehand, here is a way with `sample` and [`replicate`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html).

From the help page of `replicate`:

> `replicate` is a wrapper for the common use of `sapply` for repeated evaluation of an expression (which will usually involve random number generation).

See also [Allan Cameron's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76676438/populating-a-matrix-with-1s-row-wise/76676869?noredirect=1#comment135185149_76676869) and my answer to it.

```r
nr <- 600L
nc <- 20L
v <- c(1L, rep(0L, nc - 1L))
Chickens <- t(replicate(nr, sample(v)))

rowSums(Chickens)
#>   [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#>  [38] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#>  [75] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> [112] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> [149] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> [186] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> [223] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> [260] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> [297] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> [334] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> [371] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> [408] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> [445] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> [482] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> [519] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> [556] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> [593] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

Answer to [Paul's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76676438/populating-a-matrix-with-1s-row-wise/76676869?noredirect=1#comment135184931_76676869). Repeat the code above `R` times and compute the mean values of the `Chicken` matrix columns' sums. Add plots, a picture is worth a thousand words.

```r
R <- 1e3
sim <- replicate(R, {
  Chickens <- t(replicate(nr, sample(v)))
  colSums(Chickens)
})
str(sim)
#>  num [1:20, 1:1000] 28 33 41 35 37 30 26 26 35 26 ...

# averaged across R replicates the means per column are close
# to 30, they approximately follow a uniform distribution
rowMeans(sim)
#>  [1] 29.956 30.269 30.089 30.384 29.918 29.856 29.931 29.950 30.104 30.149
#> [11] 29.829 29.710 30.049 29.968 30.332 30.077 29.871 29.732 29.890 29.936
barplot(rowMeans(sim))
```

[image]

```r
# grand stats
mean(sim)
#> [1] 30
hist(sim)
abline(v = mean(sim), col = "blue", lty = "dashed")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Is this guaranteed or "just" very very likely to result in at least one `1` per column?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Just very very likely, 600/20 == 30. SO I expect the number of 1´s per column to follow a symmetric distribution asymptotically normal with mean 30. Give me a moment, will edit.

Comment: The one-liner `Chickens <- t(replicate(600, sample(rep(0:1, c(29, 1)))))` would do just as well here if this was a one-off requirement.

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, correcting `c(29, 1)` to `c(19, 1)`. Or `Chickens <- t(replicate(600L, sample(c(1L, rep(0L, 20L - 1L)))))`, to use my vector `v`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a multinomial distribution with `size = 1`, `20` groups and `600` observations:

in R you could do:

```
Chickens <- t(rmultinom(600, 1, rep(1, 20)))
table(rowSums(Chickens))
   1 
 600 
dim(Chickens)
[1] 600  20
```

Notice that we `t` the data since the observations are given as columns.

---

Another way is to simply sample 600 values from 20 values and convert to one hot encoding:

```
diag(20)[sample(20, 600, TRUE), ]
```

---

Another way to convert to one-hot vector is to use `model.matrix`